# segmentation fault when using gethostbyname

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to create a proxy server which accepts requests from client and sends the response back to client after receiving message from the server.
But the program gives segmentation fault.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    struct hostent *host;
    int s1,s2,s3,len;
    int port;
    char ip[100];
    char path[100];
    int p;
    int n;
    char buffer[500];
    char site[500];
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s1 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(bind(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) == -1) {
        perror("can't bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(s1,10) == -1) {
        perror("coudnt't listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    len = sizeof(client);
    s2 = accept(s1,(struct sockaddr *)&client,&len);
    if(s2 == -1) {
        perror("coudnt aceept");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    n = recv(s2,buffer,500,0);
    if(n < 0) {
        perror("not recieved");
        exit(1);
    }

    sscanf(buffer, "http://%99[^:]:%99d/%99[^\n]", ip, &p, path);
    bzero((char *)&client,sizeof(client));
    client.sin_port = htons(80);
    host = gethostbyname(ip);
    bcopy((char *)host->h_addr,(char *)&client.sin_addr.s_addr,host->h_length);
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s3 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);


    if(connect(s3,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client)) == -1) {
        perror("can't connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(site,"GET http://%s/ HTTP/1.0\n\n",ip);
    n = send(s3,site,strlen(site),0);
    if(n < 0) {
        perror("message not sent");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        memset(site,0,sizeof(site));
        n = recv(s3,site,500,0);
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("coudnot read");
            exit(1);
        }
        site[n] = '\0';
        send(s2,site,strlen(site),0);
    }
    close(s1);
    close(s2);
    return 0;

}
```

The mistake seems to be coming from `gethostbyname(ip)` because when I use `gethostbyname("www.iiita.ac.in")`, it works.

Comment: What is ip when you call gethostbyname?

Comment: ip is the domain name like "www.google.com".

Comment: (after recv()): `site[n] = '\0';` n could be 500 here.

Answer (score 1):

`gethostbyname` returns a null pointer in case of error and, thus, `host->h_addr` is a null dereference.

You need to check whether `host` is `NULL` or not before using it.

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html

Comment: When I check before using it, it gives "unknown host" error. But same works if I use "www.google.com" in place of ip.

Comment: `gethostbyname` is not designed to be used with IPs.

Comment: Sry, I am not talking about that IP. I am using a char array ip in my program which contains "www.googke.com"

Comment: Btw. have you checked that ip contains the correct value and is correctly null terminated?

Comment: I used printf to print the ip and it printed "www.google.com"